# Querying (and filtering) in a many-to-many relationship in Backand

Tags: backand

I'm trying to use the pet-owner example to create some sort of playlist app where a playlist can be shared among different users.

I have read both links to understand how many-to-many relationship is created in Backand:

**[Link 1](http://docs.backand.com/en/latest/getting_started/objects/#many-to-many-relationship) -
[Link 2](http://codepen.io/yariv/pen/eJQPEz?editors=0010)**

According to pet's example, to get all owners from one pet I should get the pet object (using its id field) and then filter its user_pets list matching the user id. That may work for small amount of users/pets but I'd rather prefer to query user_pets table directly by filtering by user_id and pet_id.

My approach has been this code without success:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: getUrl(),  // this maps to pets_owner "table"
  params: {
    deep: true,
    exclude: 'metadata',
    filter: [
      { fieldName: 'pet', operator: 'equals', value: pet_id },
      { fieldName: 'owner', operator: 'equals', value: user_id }
    ]
  }
})
```

Any idea how to query/filter to get only related results?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that my code is intented to resolve one main situation: get the relationship id and then send a DELETE to REST API to delete it. If this can be done in another way it will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Because user_id and pet_d are both object fields the operator should be "in"

From [Backand docs](http://docs.backand.com/en/latest/apidocs/apidescription/#rest-api-crud-operations) :

> following are the possible operators depending on the field type:
>
> numeric or date fields:
>
> -- equals
>
> ....
>
> object fields:
>
> -- in